# GIT ignores Proxy Configuration in CentOS

Tags: git, github, proxy, centos

I try to clone a git rep to my CentOS machine.
Problem is whatever i try git ignores my proxy setup and throws this error message when trying to clone netbox:

`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/netbox-community/netbox.git/': OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443`

We use a cisco wsa as proxy and i setup the proxy without authentication for my machine.

I set the proxy via environment variables and directly in git config via

`git config --global http.proxy http://webproxy.tld:8080`

I also tried:

`git config --global https.proxy http://webproxy.tld:8080`

But it still wont use the proxy. I can see it on the firewall that my server is trying to access github directly via firewall gateway the proxy server has no log entrys.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The proxy does not must have protocol prefix, so please try with:

`git config --global http.proxy webproxy.tld:8080`

Or into your `.bashrc`:

`export http_proxy=webproxy.tld:8080`

Please, let me know if it worked.

Comment: I tried it without protocol now but still the same effect. Git tries to go via its gateway and ignores proxy configuration. I can see the connection in our firewall.

Comment: This is not correct.  One can and should specify the protocol.  There are HTTP proxies, HTTPS proxies, SOCKS4 and SOCKS5 proxies, etc. and the protocol is required to specify which type it is.  You _may_ omit it in some cases, but specifying it is recommended in all cases and required in some.

Comment: It doesn't work either way, i had the protocol configured before, so that doesnt seem to be the problem.